# Azure Web App & Application insights - logging

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

On Azure Web App page, I need to log all visits (pass & error) into diagnostics/Azure storage.. Probably it works with a couple of clicks.

But, except that, I need to create Application Insights, which could pickup and store all logs and show them off on some specific place.
Without(!!) SDK, without reprogramming, without integration into some app, something like on this link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now

I need to log server response time and amounts by response type (http 200, 404, 500...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Kristian. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Currently, this question will likely be closed unless you modify it. It is currently unclear what you are asking here because you haven't actually asked a question. Additionally, if you want us to help you then you need to tell us about the problem you are having. It's clear you want to implement Application Insights at the infrastructure level, and that's possible. What is keeping you from doing it? What can we do to help you?

Comment: I need to log response time to my Web App and log responses sent to users joined my webpage (404,500,200)... Forward it to some place where I can list them by user, watch the amount of these messages, timestamp of every of these etc.

Comment: I understand that is what you need to do. Why can't you do it? You provided a link to documentation that tells how to do it. What problem are you having?

Comment: Problem is, that I should make run-time logging without implementing SDK.

Comment: But the top section in the article that you linked explains how to do it on Azure web app without manually adding SDK and redeploying: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now#monitor-a-live-azure-web-app. Can you explain why this is not an option for you?

Comment: Because it actually won't load and start logging without implementing it.

Comment: Is it possible to run it without any SDK (man/auto)?

Comment: Yes. The link you provided explains how to do this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps This is the document if the app is deployed as Azure Web App. The original doc linked is for non web app scenarios.